# Java Synchronized Write Block

Tags: java, synchronized-block

im new to java and i have a question regarding Synchronized.

i have the following code for writing to network (simple implementation for now):

```
public void networkSendData(byte[] data){

    try {

        out.write(data);
        out.flush();

    } catch (IOException e) {


    }
}
```

i was wondering if there is a need for block level Synchronized here as im am writing the whole data at once. or is there a chance for race condition? i ask because the data to write is coming for multiple sources.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your example, there is no need to have a `synchronize`d block unless multiple threads are going to have access to the same `out` variable.

In other words, if you have multiple threads all calling `networkSendData` at the same time, you should `synchronize` the method. You do not want to have one thread calling `flush` while another thread is half way through executing the `write` method.

```
public synchronized void networkSendData(byte[] data)
```

You will also need to make sure that no threads are accessing/modifying the value of the `out` variable while there is a chance that another thread can be in the `networkSendData` method.

<strike>This depends on how the server that is receiving the written data handles it. If multiple threads are used to update a shared mutable variable based on what is written to the server, you will need to implement thread safety.</strike>

Comment: on the server-side there is only one thread listending for incoming data.

Comment: thanks that is what i was wondering. multiple nodes transmitting at the same time (rare but could happen).